# How to list the records in horizontal order using modulus (%) operation?

Tags: php, html

I have problem in my task where I suppose to display my record in horizontally with 3 columns

Unfortunately, my display is become vertical.

The task require us to use modulus (%) operator in order to display the records. The records are stored in database (id, title, picture, category, author). There are 11 books that store in database. Here is my PHP code:

```
<?php
include_once('config.php');
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM books ORDER BY id ASC");
?>

<style>
img {
border: 1px solid #ddd;
border-radius: 4px;
padding: 5px;
width: 200px;
}

.p2 {
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 14px;
padding-left: 10px;
}

.p3 {
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 14px;
padding-left: 10px;
color: blue;
}
</style>



<div class="container">
    

    <center>
        <h1>Koleksi Buku Peribadi</h1>
        <table>
            <?php
            $x=11;
            $y=3;
            $i=$x % $y;
            while($i && $book = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            ?>

            <tr>
                <td>
                <img src="Gambar-buku/<?php echo $book['picture'];?>">

                <p class='p2'>Penulis:<span class='p3'> <?php echo $book['author'];?> </span>
                <br> <i><?php echo $book['category'];?></i>
                </p> 
                
                <center><button type="button">Details</button> </center>                                 
                </td>  
            </tr>

            <?php
                $i++; }
            ?>                         
        </table>
    </center>

   
</div>
```

Comment: `while($i % 3` isn't logical. The modulus is likely to be different for different values of $i. Hence why it stops after one loop. You need to use the modulus value _within the loop_ to decide whether to start a new `<tr>` or not.

Comment: already change the loop and the value of $i, but it display vertically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modulus is useful when you need to **equally divide items into several categories**.

Formally: `index_of_category = index_of_item % number_of_categories`

Practically: In your case, you have 3 categories (columns). For item with index `i`, you find index of its column with `i % 3`.

For making table layout work, you then need to:

- print `tr` opening tag for every item belonging in column with index 0
- print `tr` closing tag for every item belonging in column with index 2.

In my example, you can change number of columns easily by modifying `$numberOfColumns` variable.

```php
<div class="container">
    <center>
        <h1>Koleksi Buku Peribadi</h1>
        <table>
<?php
    $numberOfColumns = 3;
    for ($i = 0; (($book = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) !== null); $i++) {
      $printRowOpeningTag = $i % $numberOfColumns === 0;
      $printRowClosingTag = $i % $numberOfColumns === $numberOfColumns - 1;
      if ($printRowOpeningTag) {?>
          <tr>
<?php } ?>
            <td><img src="Gambar-buku/<?php echo $book['picture'];?>">
                <p class='p2'>Penulis:<span class='p3'> <?php echo $book['author'];?> </span>
                <br> <i><?php echo $book['category'];?> </i>
                </p> 
                <center><button type="button">Details</button> </center>                                 
            </td>
<?php if ($printRowClosingTag) { ?>
          </tr>
<?php } ?>
<?php 
    } ?>
        </table>
    </center>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, it work perfectly thnks to you again

Comment: I have question, the opening tag will print tr with index 0, right. How about index 1 ?

Comment: @thenoobies On index 1, no <tr> tag is printed, because it is neither the start nor the end of the a row.